# How to connect impala database from nodejs

Tags: node.js, impala

I have an access to connect Impala database connection through UI where I can run my `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME` Queries. How can I establish connection from Node js server side and run the same select statement through my Node APIs and functions.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) to find out what questions are appropriate to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [node-impala npm packet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-impala) for this.

Here is an example:

```
import { createClient } from 'node-impala';
 
const client = createClient();
 
client.connect({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 21000,
  resultType: 'json-array'
});
 
client.query('SELECT column_name FROM table_name')
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .done(() => client.close().catch(err => console.error(err)));
```

Comment: How the database can be authenticated? Because I have a username and password to login in UI. Same thing should be used here also right, So how it will be achievable?